# How to stop maven archetype:generate from renaming files with underscores in their name?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I have custom maven archetype that contains python code, and one of the files is `__version__.py`.

Now if I generate the project using the archetype, the file is being renamed to `1.0.py`, because the generated project version is `1.0` and `archetype:generate` detects the double underscore files as template tokens.

My `archetype-metadata.xml` simply includes everything from the archetype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet encoding="UTF-8">
      <directory></directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

Having the `filtered` option (true or false) for `fileSet` appears to have no impact on the outcome.

Comment: Strange. It would have thought that `filtered="false"` should avoid the behaviour.

Comment: Looked up the source code, and couldn't figure out from there either how to disable the mechanism: https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/blob/master/archetype-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/generator/DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java
The `getOutputFile()` is generic method for which the behavior appears to be same regardless of `filtered` being enabled or disabled.

Comment: Checking that code link, it looks like anything matching TOKEN_PATTERN is replaced. It appears to be anything inside double underscores. I didn't see a way to override either.